# Why does Visual Studio's error list stop at 102 errors?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, compiler-errors

I can see why it chooses to stop after it's found a given number of errors.

But why stop at 102? Why not 99, 100 or 128?

Comment: Ah, us programmers, considering `128` a nice, round number. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft [this is by design.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/88838/error-count-maxxes-out-at-102-errors)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I think that it's like 101 is the first value over 100.
Then add one for the `too many errors` error and you get 102.

But the rule might be when it reaches over 100 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it stops after the file that contains the 100<sup>th</sup> error.

This would mean that if the error count was 99 (say) and there were 3 errors in the file it would report all three giving 102. If there were 5 errors then it would report 104.